# If a cell contains any of these values, then label as this

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formula, formulas

I want to set up a formula in Excel so if column B (which contains dates) contains any of the dates in a list of 7 dates, then it will be labeled as "Week 1", but if not, it'll be labeled as "Week 2". The formula listed below is returning #NAME error. Any thoughts?

ie: =IF((B1,containsAny=J1:J7), "Week 1", "Week 2")

Pic: http://i57.tinypic.com/2vlk4g5.png

Comment: Isn't the `WEEKNUM` function useful for you? Aren't these actual calendar weeks? 1/9 and 9/9 both belong to "Week 1"? You get that error because that "containsAny" is invalid in Excel.

Comment: Will there be more weeks afterwards?

Comment: Mindy, could you check the questions and answers you received?

Comment: Still there? Your profile says "Last seen Sep 21 at 5:41". :(

Answer (score 1):

As per your screenshot, you can get the date's week by using the `WEEKNUM` function. For example, assuming your dates start at row 10, you could place this formula in cell `I10` and copy it to the cells below, and you will get the week number.

`=WEEKNUM(B10,15)-36`

The second parameter defines when your week starts (15 = Friday in your case), and that week is the 37th of the year, so I simply subtract 36. :)

With this approach, you don't need to hardcode any dates like in cells J1:K7, and it's future-proof. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you found the containsAny function, but that's what throws the error for me.

Why not try

```
=IF(A1=B1:B7, "Week1", "Week2")
```

That worked for me, using Excel 2011's formula builder.

Comment: It does? In my case, it only returns "Week1" for the first row (9/1), and not for 9/2 and 9/3. I think it's only comparing with the first value of the range.

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,B1:B7,1,FALSE))), "Week1", "Week2")`

I am sure there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: As soon as week 3 appears, this starts to get ugly.

Comment: I really dont know what OP is trying. What I am doing is returning Week1 if a date is found in a list of dates, Week2 otherwise.

Comment: Yes, of course. But in cases like this usually what the person asks is not what the person needs. ;)